# How does file loading in DOM work?

Tags: java, xml, dom, memory

I've been looking at loading XML files with Java and I just can't seem to decipher a certain part of it.
I understand that SAX is a streaming mechanism, but when talking about DOM, various sites talk about the model "loading in the full file" or "loading in the all tags", supported by the recommendation to use SAX with large XML files.

To what degree does DOM actually load the full file? The second I access the root node, does it allocate program memory for every single byte of the file? Does it only load tags until the lowest level when it loads text contents?

I'm going to be working with large files, but random access would be useful and editing is a requirement, so I believe DOM is the best choice for me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transform huge xml files in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773733/how-to-transform-huge-xml-files-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does load the entire file and constructs a tree structure in memory. Thus, every single tag, attribute and any nested tags (no matter how many levels of nesting) will be loaded. It is just that the constructed tree grows bigger the larger the XML file you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) ... Well, everyone answered but you were first :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DOM reads the whole document, parses it, and places it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing using DOM, you do something similar to this:

```
 DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = builder.parse(file);
```

(inside a try/catch)

The moment the parse is executed, the `Document doc` variable will contain the entire document represented as a DOM  hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
File fin = new File("items.xml"); //getxml
Document doc = builder.parse(fin); //parse into document/root element
XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath(); //Xpath object used to query "doc"
```

For example:

```
String result = path.evaluate("/items/item[1]/quantity", doc);
System.out.println("quantity of product[1] = " + result);


package za.nmu.wrpv.example02androidclient;
//
NETWORK
```

package za.nmu.wrpv.example02androidclient;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onConnectClicked(View view) {
        // Get server address.
        EditText edtServerAddress = findViewById(R.id.edtServerAddress);
        String address = edtServerAddress.getText().toString();

        // Start other communication activity, passing server address.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CommunicationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Server Address", address);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
  


public class CommunicationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private String serverAddress;
    private CommunicationThread communicationThread = null;
    private ListView lstMessages;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_communication);

        // Add event handler for when user presses enter key.
        EditText edtMessage = findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
        edtMessage.setOnKeyListener((view, i, keyEvent) -> {
            // If not busy communicating, do nothing.
            if(communicationThread == null) return false;

            // Did not press the enter key, do nothing.
            if ((keyEvent.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    || (keyEvent.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) return false;

            // Busy communicating with server and pressed enter key, so send message.
            String message = edtMessage.getText().toString();

            // Call method to send message on output stream to server. CANNOT be done
            // on the UI thread.
            new Thread(() -> communicationThread.sendMessage(message)).start();

            // Clear the edit text.
            edtMessage.setText("");

            // Done, so indicate processed event.
            return true;
        });

        // RecyclerView is the more "current" way of doing it, but the set up code
        // is a LOT longer - so not really worth the effort for this example.
        lstMessages = findViewById(R.id.lstMessages);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new ArrayList<String>());
        lstMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Check whether have permission to use the internet.
        boolean hasPermission =
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        // Get server address from intent.
        try {
            serverAddress = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Server Address");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            serverAddress = "Undefined";
        }

        // Display initial settings.
        addMessage("Internet Permission = " + hasPermission
                + "\nServer Address = " + serverAddress);

        // Open connection.
        openConnection();
    }

    private void openConnection() {
        communicationThread = new CommunicationThread(
                serverAddress, // Address to connect too
                value -> runOnUiThread(() -> addMessage(value)), // How to display messages.
                () -> runOnUiThread(() -> finish())); // What to do when connection closed.
        communicationThread.start();
    }

    public void addMessage(String message) {
        adapter.add(message);
        lstMessages.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (communicationThread == null) return;

        // Send message to server to let it know that the connection is to be
        // terminated.
        new Thread(() -> communicationThread.sendMessage("TERMINATE")).start();
    }
}

public class CommunicationThread extends Thread {
    // Server IP address.
    private String serverAddress;
    // Displayer function to display messages on...
    private Displayer<String> displayer;
    // Code to call when communication is completed...
    private Runnable onCompleted;

    // Network communication fields
    private Socket conn = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    private ObjectInputStream ois = null;

    public CommunicationThread(String serverAddress, Displayer<String> displayer, Runnable onCompleted) {
        super(serverAddress);
        this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
        this.displayer = displayer;
        this.onCompleted = onCompleted;
    }

    // Called by another thread to send a message.
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject("CLIENT>>> " + message);
            oos.flush();
            display("CLIENT>>>" + message);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            display("ERROR: Error writing object");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Connect to server.
            conn = new Socket(serverAddress, 5001);
            display("Connecting to: " + conn.getInetAddress().getHostName());

            // Get and initialise streams.
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            display("Got I/O streams");

            // Read messages from server until told to terminate.
            String message = "";

            do {
                message = (String) ois.readObject();
                display(message);
            } while (!message.equals("SERVER>>> TERMINATE"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            display("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            // Close connection.
            close();

            display("Disconnected...");
        }
    }

    private void display(String message) {
        // If not displayer provided, do nothing.
        if(displayer == null) return;

        // Otherwise, display it.
        displayer.display(message);
    }

    private void close() {
        try {
            conn.close();

            // Was an onCompleted runnable provided? If so, run it.
            if(onCompleted != null) onCompleted.run();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            display("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It looks like you took some time to write some code to do something related to what the poster was asking. Having said that, the question is about how the file is processed.