# Storing triples efficiently

Tags: java, python, linux, semantics, semantic-web

I have about a Tera Byte large file. I want to convert it from nt to n3. The reason for doing so is, I have a large file which consumes a lot of space due to attached namespaces:

```
# <1>
<file:///home//uniprot/uniprot.rdf>    <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#imports> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/> .
# <2>
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/Protein> .
# <3>
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/reviewed> "true"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean> .
```

Now I want to store this file efficiently in a compressed form as:

```
@fileuniprot: <file:///home//uniprot/>.
@owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
@purlUniprot: <http://purl.uniprot.org/>.
@rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.
@xsd: 
# <1>
fileuniprot:uniprot.rdf    owl:imports purlUniprot:core .
# <2>
purlUniprot:uniprot/Q6GZX4 rdfs:type purlUniprot:core/Protein .
# <3>
purlUniprot:Q6GZX4 purlUniprot:core/reviewed "true"^^ xsd:boolean .
```

i.e. I dont want the namespaces to be attached with the corresponding triples. Although I want to retain the comments. Is it possible to do so. If yes, then can someone please suggest an efficient tool for doing the same.

It would be great if I could find some tool in python or java which works with linux?
I have done the above manually, it would be great if the conversion could be done automatically.

Comment: You really just a String => String mapping. Simple stuff actually. It doesn't look like you can do much to generalise it since you mapped `<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#imports>` to `<imports>` and `<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>` to `<type>`

Comment: If there are other changes in xml other than simple string conversion you can use the `XSLT transformer` with `SAX parser`. Also have a look  at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773733/how-to-transform-huge-xml-files-in-java

Comment: @Cruncher Actually i have to find the common patterns and then replace them. Is there someway by which I could find common patterns and could replace them programatically

Comment: This seems like the kind of transformation that text compression typically handles pretty well.  Could you just gzip and zcat as you need it?

Comment: The conversion nt -> n3 will reduce the size of the plain file, because you remove the namespaces, as mentioned. However, it seems to me that further compression will eventually lead the same size with either starting format, as text compression algorithms will try to map and remove redundant text as much as possible. So make sure it is not the case first with a small sample before going large scale. Jerven, Uniprot's RDF father has been trying different compression methods recently (https://twitter.com/jervenbolleman/status/395193185007198208), worth checking.

Comment: @loopasam, yeah but I answered the question below ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [hdt](http://www.rdfhdt.org/) for very good compression.
You can change the uniprot file back to rdf/xml compressed with gzip and reduce size by a factor of at least 25. (bzip2 will give 30) I recommend using pbzip2 for best results.

If you do want to use turtle syntax for some compression then using pre existing code from [sesame RIO](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view), [jena RIOT](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/) or rapper from [librdf](http://librdf.org/)

The questions is why did you want the file as nt to start with?

The file format you are actually thinking of using is called turtle. N3 is turtle plus rules, this rule part is not actually used in the UniProt data set and falls outside of just RDF/triples.

```
rapper -i ntriples -o turtle ~/uniprot.nt  > ~/uniprot.ttl
```

Forget about N3 read up on turtle instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure I can use rapper from rdflib. But I am not getting how to use the rapper to convert from nt to .n3