# XSLT fails to transform bigger XML file. Process getting killed becauase of memory overhead

Tags: java, xml, performance, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a XML file having 9GB size. I want to transform this to another xml file.

I'm using xslt 2.0 and saxon 8.7.

But when i'm executing the following code , process is getting killed automatically after some time.

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(sourcePath));
xsltTransformer.transform(new StreamSource(stream), new StreamResult(new File(resultDir)));
```

I dont't want to use any commercial version of Saxon(saxon-EE).PLease help me to use memory efficiently.

Note : The server on which i'm running the code is a virtual amazon machine of type medium so the memory is less than 4 Gb. Transformation of 1 GB file is working properly.

Comment: I'd suggest to use SAX - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773733/how-to-transform-huge-xml-files-in-java

Comment: Well Saxon 8.7 is that old that it does not even implement the XSLT 2.0 standard from 2007, I think Saxon 8.9 was the first Saxon release that did that. But I don't think any XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 implementation can handle a file of that size in that environment. Even Saxon EE does not magically avoid memory issues, you would need to try to write a stylesheet using streaming.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Can you give any idea how to write using Streaming.

Comment: @RudolfYurgenson Thanks for reply.I will go through it.

Comment: See http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/ if you want to use that approach, I am not really familiar with the details and its a moving target currently. And of course anyone that should help you with a precise description needs to see your XML input structure, your current XSLT and the result you want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen but this approch requires  Saxon-EE which is commercial version.

Comment: You're out of luck. If you want to transform a document of this size using XSLT, you'll need a processor that implements streaming, and that's an expensive thing to develop so no-one is currently offering one for free. Your situation isn't unusual -- a lot of projects seem prepared to pay more for programmers' time and for hosting services than for software licenses -- but when you want to scale to this level, you need stuff that can't be developed by amateurs working in their spare time.